# How can I create a Java class file from a Java file from my program?

Tags: java

Suppose there is a Java file that exists in an external folder. Can I write a Java program which will generate a .class file of that Java file and place the .class file in the same external folder?

Comment: No Sir. Surely javac can create class file from a .java file. But I have to do that without using javac and to run my own program to create that class.

Comment: what do you mean with external?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way (for me) is to include `tools.jar` and to invoke the `com.sun.tools.javac.Main.compile(`) function.

Comment: Note that `sun.tools.javac.Main` is replaced by `javax.tools.JavaCompiler` refer [here](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/javacmain.html)

Comment: @PauKiatWee you're right, I just feel more comfortable ("...the easiest way...") with the old quick and dirty interface.

Comment: can u please tell me where can I download the tools.jar? And one thing, this codeI have to implement in struts 1 frmawork.

Comment: Usually in the lib directory of root Java SDK installation directory.

Comment: @Adriano Thanks all of you for the help. I have placed the tools.jar in my eclipse lib. But still I am not able to use javax.tools.JavaCompiler. Can't I use this code for my sturts application?

Comment: @SweetDream Put it on $JDK/jre/lib/endorsed/

Answer (score 1):

yes , you can do it using java compiler

```
JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
StandardJavaFileManager fileManager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(null,null,null);
```

[Check this for further details](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html)

Answer (score 0):

It's in here: [`java.lang.Compiler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Compiler.html).
This class has the method `compileClass(Class class)` and `compileClasses(String names)`

Comment: The Compiler class should be deprecated. It has nothing to do with compiling Java source code, and in modern JVMs, it doesn't do anything at all.

Comment: According to the documentation, it does. I updated the link to point to the Java 6 documentation. @boneill

Comment: Can you provide a working example of this class compiling Java source code?