# Get result of compiling a Java source file, within another Java class, using JavaCompiler package

Tags: java, java-compiler-api

I have the following (simplified) code, within my class, which invokes the Java Compiler to process a given source file:

```
package test;
import javax.tools.*;

public class SimpleCompileTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String fileToCompile = "MyClass.java";

        JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
        int compilationResult = compiler.run(null, null, null, fileToCompile);

        if(compilationResult == 0){
            System.out.println("Compilation is successful");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Compilation Failed");
        }
    }
}
```

The compilation succeeds, but now how can i get the result of MyClass.java, how to run this compiled code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10480046/how-can-i-create-a-java-class-file-from-a-java-file-from-my-program

Answer (score 0):

```
package javacompiler;
import javax.tools.JavaCompiler;
import javax.tools.ToolProvider;
public class COmpilerHello {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String s="C:/Users/MariaHussain/Desktop/hussi.java";
        JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
        int result = compiler.run(System.in,System.out,System.err,s);
        System.out.println("Compile result code = " + result);
    }
}
```

see the various value of result variale like 0,1 2 show the comilation state , whether it is compiled or not

Answer (score 0):

get JavaFileManager, set location to save .class files and then load it via (custom) class loader:

```
StandardJavaFileManager stdFileManager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(null, Locale.getDefault(), null);

stdFileManager.setLocation(StandardLocation.CLASS_OUTPUT, Arrays.asList(new File("classDir")));

 + custom classloader
```

---

Or without storing:
[JavaCompiler from JDK 1.6: how to write class bytes directly to byte[] array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130039/javacompiler-from-jdk-1-6-how-to-write-class-bytes-directly-to-byte-array)

where you get pointed to:
https://weblogs.java.net/blog/2008/12/17/how-compile-fly

where the main idea is to use custom MemoryFileManager as JavaFileManager.